# Is there an advantage to using a continue block with a while loop in Perl?

Tags: perl

**SYNTAX 1:**

```
while {
#some code 
}
continue {
#some other code 
}
```

**SYNTAX 2:**

```
while {
#some code 
#some other code
}
```

Does SYNTAX 1 has any advantage over SYNTAX 2 ? assuming "some code"and "some other code" remain same set of lines in both the syntaxes. Or its just two different styles having no coding advantage.

Comment: I think this is a very good question and I don't understand why anyone would downvote this. The perldoc does not do a good job of explaining why this is useful, and I've thought about this exact question myself every time I thought _hey I could use a `continue` here... or maybe not_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `continue` block executes when you call `next` from the middle of the loop, so it provides a way to execute some common code between iterations, regardless of the path of execution through each iteration.

Compare

```
my $last_item;
for my $item (@list) {
   if ($last_item eq $item) {
       do_something();
       $last_item = $item;
       next;
   }

   if (condition2($item,$last_item)) {
       $last_item = $item;
       next;
   }

   do_something_else();
   $last_item = $item;
}
```

with

```
my $last_item;
for my $item (@list) {
   if ($last_item eq $item) {
       do_something();
       next;
   }

   if (condition2($item,$last_item)) {
       next;
   }

   do_something_else();
} continue {
   $last_item = $item;
}
```

Some examples of `continue` in the wild:

[`HTTP::Cookies`](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/HTTP-Cookies-6.04/lib/HTTP/Cookies.pm#L143)

[`PPIx::Regexp::Node`](https://metacpan.org/source/WYANT/PPIx-Regexp-0.052/lib/PPIx/Regexp/Node.pm#L353)

[`PDL::Core`](https://metacpan.org/source/CHM/PDL-2.018/Basic/Core/Core.pm#L1234)

Comment: no , I dont think so when using continue with a BLOCK it behaves differently , please read this https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html

Comment: @Vicky actually the docs say pretty much the same, just in different words. mob is spot-on, and has a good example. They just didn't explain about `last` and `redo`, but the answer is sound. I like the reference of real code on CPAN.

Comment: What if I remove the "next" statement from the second code block of mob , code in continue block will still execute right ?

Comment: `perl -pe'...'` uses `continue` too: `LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    ...
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}` (I wish it didn't, though.)

Comment: @Vicky: If you remove the second `next` statement then it will fall through and call `do_something_else`. As it stands it will skip that call and go straight to the `continue` block.